# How to track the percentage of the video watched using Komito Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, html5-video, komito-analytics

Komito Analytics allow to track media events like "play", "pause" and "ended" of embedded HTML5, Vimeo and YouTube videos. (https://komito.net/integration/)

But does it support tracking the percentage of the videos watched?
I am particularly interested in HTML5 video.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question, currently Komito Analytics cannot track the percentage of the videos watched due to lot of reasons.

But you can use this simple script to track the percentage of watched HTML5 videos:
https://gist.github.com/vpodk/7306f657995985bf27de5a858c909ca4

This script also supports dynamic content, steps, and examples for `analytics.js` and `gtag.js`.